# connect to db every minute using pool

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I want to connect PostgreSQL database every minute using pool. 
my function is:

```
module.exports.deleteExpiredAd = function(callback) {
    var response = {};
    var queryText = "begin transaction; 
                 update ad set deleted=true where date_to < current_date; 
                 update ad_ad_group set deleted=true from ad where 
                 ad.date_to < current_date; 
                 commit;"
    pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {
        if(err) {
            response.code = 1;
            callback(err, response, 400);
            return console.error('error fetching client from pool', err);
        }
        client.query(queryText, function(err, result) {
            client.release();
            if(err) {
                   console.log(err);
                   response.code = 1;
                   response.message = 'expired ads have not been deleted';
                   callback(err, response, 400);
                   return console.error('error running query', err.code);
            }       
            response.code = 0;
            response.message = 'expired ads have been deleted'
            //client.destroy()
            callback(err, response, 201);
      });
    });
};
```

And this function Im calling from another file using setTimeout (I tried setInterval, but there is no difference)

```
var checker = function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
      console.log("calling api")
      modelAd.deleteExpiredAd(function(){

      })
  },60000);
}
checker();
```

But when I start server, the error appears:
[image]

I already tried to close pool before function ends, but then Im not sure if it is possible to reopen it.

Comment: You wouldn't have this problem with [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), which does connections automatically. And as a bonus, it also supports automatic transactions ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var checker = function(){
  setInterval(function(){
      console.log("calling api")
      modelAd.deleteExpiredAd(function(){

      })
  },60000);
}
checker();
```

1000 is 1 second so the client limit gets exceeded because its being called every second not every minute. 60000 is 1 minute in milliseconds

Also make it so the pool is closed each time the function is called:

```
module.exports.deleteExpiredAd = function(callback) {
    var response = {};
    var queryText = "begin transaction; 
                 update ad set deleted=true where date_to < current_date; 
                 update ad_ad_group set deleted=true from ad where 
                 ad.date_to < current_date; 
                 commit;"
    pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {
        if(err) {
            response.code = 1;
            callback(err, response, 400);
            return console.error('error fetching client from pool', err);
        }
        client.query(queryText, function(err, result) {
            client.end(callback)
            if(err) {
                   console.log(err);
                   response.code = 1;
                   response.message = 'expired ads have not been deleted';
                   callback(err, response, 400);
                   return console.error('error running query', err.code);
            }       
            response.code = 0;
            response.message = 'expired ads have been deleted'
            //client.destroy()
            callback(err, response, 201);
      });
    });
};
```

Comment: unfortunately yes

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: @Hanka see updated edit. You may need to close the client as well

Comment: thank you @Deckerz for your help. I solved it. 
I couldnt use client.destroy() because of some error: is not function. So I was googling and I found this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157894/node-js-request-mysql-and-connection-pooling-leads-to-infinite-blocking-freezi)
where is written I can use client.end(callback). And its working :)
pool.end() I cant use. Its closing connection and not reopening it.